# Sonarqube plugin: create an issue from a MeasureComputer

Tags: sonarqube

From Issuable class javadoc:

> This perspective allows to add issues related to the selected
>   component. It can be used from org.sonar.api.batch.Sensors.

I wonder if it's possible to create an issue from a MeasureComputer? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

MeasureComputer extension point does not allow to create issues. It aims to create and aggregate measures. Only scanner Sensor extension point can create issue.